# Java: Arrays.equals not working

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which is a byte[] of a file I've read in. I need to check the first 5 bytes of the file. To begin I did this:

```
if (ips_bytes[0] != ips_ident[0] && ips_bytes[1] != ips_ident[1] && ips_bytes[2] != ips_ident[2]
            && ips_bytes[3] != ips_ident[3] && ips_bytes[4] != ips_ident[4]) {
        return "Nope!";
    }
```

This works, but it doesn't look very nice and I guess it's not very efficient. So I looked into other methods and found Arrays.equals(). I changed my code to reflect that:

```
if (!Arrays.equals(ips_ident, Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_bytes, 0, 4))) {
        return "Baka";
    }
```

This didn't work, and I tried 0, 4 and 1, 5 to see if the ranges were different. Am I missing something because this looks right? The array values are definitely correct.

Comment: Maybe the arrays aren't equal

Comment: Your first example only evaluates to `true` if _every single comparison_ fails (you're using `&&`).  The second one will fail if _any_ comparison fails.  The logic isn't even close to similar.

Comment: You want to use `Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_bytes, 0, ips_ident.length)` to be sure you get a matching range of elements

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, that works.

Answer (score 6):

Your conditions are not equivalent.

First one will be true if all pairs of corresponding elements are not equal

The second will be true if exists at least one pair of elements that aren't equal

I believe you need the second code, but you need to fix it a bit. 
[Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)'s third parameter-index is exculeded. So you need

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_bytes, 0, 5))
```

or better

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_bytes, 0, ips_ident.length))
```

Comment: If at least one fails it will bring back a failure? That's still an issue since every one of them match up, why would it return a failure?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it should the same range of bytes:

```
if (!Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_ident, 0, 5), Arrays.copyOfRange(ips_bytes, 0, 5)))
```

Example

```
char[] arr1 = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
char[] arr2 = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'm' };
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr1, 0, 3), Arrays.copyOfRange(arr2, 0, 3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't use unnecessary memory and is re-usable.

Just use a for loop:

```
public boolean compareFirstBytes(byte[] arrayOne, byte[] arrayTwo, int range) {
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        if (arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```